# Xcode login screen sqlite3 database authentication issue

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, authentication, sqlite

I am trying to create a login screen for an iphone application using sqlite3 to store the login credentials.

The following is the function I am using to handle the authentication:

```
-(void) enter
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &DBLogin) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connected to Database");
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id FROM User WHERE id=\"%@\"",login.text];
        NSString *s = password.text;
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        NSLog(@"String is %s",query_stmt);
        NSLog(@"Pass is %@",s);
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(DBLogin,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) ==!SQLITE_NULL)
        {
            NSLog(@"Executed Correctly");
            querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT password FROM User WHERE password=\"%@\"",password.text];
            query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
            const char *f= [login.text UTF8String];
            NSLog(@"String is %s",query_stmt);
            NSLog(@"Pass is %@",s);
            //   const char *l = [login.text UTF8String];
            //  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, query_stmt, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(DBLogin,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == !SQLITE_NULL)
            {
                if(sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1,f , -1, SQLITE_STATIC))
                    status.text= @"Congratulations";
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"error");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed");
            status.text =@"ERROR!";
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my schema for the database:

`CREATE TABLE User (id varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY, password varchar(20));`

I think there is something wrong with the way I am passing the details of `login.text` or `password.text`. According to `NSLog` it passes the right values but it seems to fail to check whether it is the right input or not. It seems to think everything is good and displays `status.text = Congratulations` no matter what I input.

I don't have any idea how to fix this and would appreciate any help I can get. I can provide more information if needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you just checking if a password exists in the database, rather than checking if the password is correct for the particular user?

Comment: I have to be able to authenticate users with data from a database. I'm not sure how to check if the password is correct for the user so any help with that would be appreciated.

Comment: How is the user data first put into the database when they install the app - is it provided with the app and they are told their username/password, or do they enter a username/password when they first run the app? What happens if they go onto another device - do you want the username and password to work on that as well? There are many many other questions that you will have to decide on

Comment: An admin would place their username and password into the database before the user is allowed to use the app. Each user would be assigned a privilege to what functions they can use with the app based on what the admin assigns for them. Eventually there are plans to push the local database to a wireless database so that people from on other devices with the same app can use the same credentials to log in but for now I want to get this to work on a local databse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted, I want to make few things clear for you and then will suggest how to proceed. There are 4 main sqlite functions used to perform a database operation

1. sqlite3_open : To open a database connection
2. sqlite3_prepare_v2: To compile the query into byte-code program
3. sqlite_bind : To pass input values to the query
4. sqlite3_step : To evaluate/execute the compiled statement.

So from the code you posted above,

1. you have not performed step 4. So its obvious that you have not executed the query at all.
2. you formed the query completely(including the input parameter) using NSString stringWithFormat method, so there is no need to use  sqlite_bind function.
3. The logic you used to authenticate user is also a bit confusing.

Here is the way to achieve what you need

```
if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
   const char *sql = "select * from User where id = ? and password = ?";
   sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
   if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
     sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt, 1, [login.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
     sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt, 2, [password.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

          NSLog(@"Successful login");
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: The code you wrote compiles but when I enter the correct username and password it doesn't enter the while loop. The code that is returned with sqlite3_step(selectstmt) is 101 which means SQLITE=DONE. Based on this is there something wrong with my database or another coding issue?

Comment: SQLITE_DONE means the statement has finished executing successfully. There is nothing wrong with the code. I doubt if there are no records in your database. Can you confirm if your database has the information about the user you are searching for?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that there are records in the database that I am entering in the login and password text fields but for some reason it won't enter the while loop to say Successful login.

Comment: I'm also starting to think this might be a database path linking issue as I run this after the if statement you wrote and nothing appears: sql = "select * from User "; if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {NSLog(@"Database2");while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {NSLog(@"Successful read");NSString *userid = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
NSString *password2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];NSLog(@"%@", userid);          NSLog(@"%@", password2);} }

Comment: Since I think the new problem is unrelated to this coding issue I will accept your answer and post a different question. thanks for your help with the authenication code!