# Xcode not recognizing local database. Can't seem to connect to sqlite3 database file

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, authentication, sqlite

I am trying to connect an sqlite3 database file I called Login.sql to my iphone appilcation I am writing. Xcode doesn't seem to recongize the file even though I tried putting in in several places including the Documents folder, the folder containing the xcode project, and the Dervived Data for the project. The following code is in the AppDelegate File under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (it used to be in the View Controller but I moved it thinking it would work.

Here is the code:
       NSString *docsDir;

```
NSArray *dirPaths;

// databaseName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DBLogin.sql" ofType:@"db"];

databaseName= @"Login.sql";

// Get the documents directory

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(

                                               NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);



docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];


NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];



// Build the path to the database file

//databasePath = [[NSString alloc]                     initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:                                     @"DBLogin.sql"]];



NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];



if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)

{


    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];





    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)

    {

        NSLog(@"DATABASE LOADED");

        char *errMsg;

        const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User (id varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY , password varchar(20))";



        if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)

        {

            status.text = @"Failed to create table";

        }



        status.text = @"Database Connected";



        sqlite3_close(database);



    } else {

        status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";

    }

}

else{

    NSLog(@"Connect!");

}




return YES;
```

The code that acceses the database file is here: [Xcode login screen sqlite3 database authentication issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244543/xcode-login-screen-sqlite3-database-authentication-issue) I'm just including it in case this code can cause the problem.

Basically everytime I place a new database in this code to see if that was the problem I think the code creates a new temporary sql database file with the a table created in the table does not exist function. I don't know what to do and this is driving me crazy. If anyone has any idea as to how to get this code to recognize my database it is appreciated. I already have the database linked to the copy bundle resources build page and it still doesnt' access it.

Let me know if you need any other information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run indent on your code.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give you the steps i take to access the `sqlite3` database.

**1.** First i create a blank sqlite database with required tables (using firefox sqlite manager add-on or any other method that is convenient). And add it in my project.

**2.** Get the path of the database file.

```
BOOL success;

NSArray*dirPath;
NSString*docDir;
NSString*databasePath;
NSString*databaseName=@"yourDB.sqlite";

//path for database
dirPath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docDir=[dirPath objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath=[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
```

**3.** Use `NSFileManager` to check if it is already present in `DocumentDirectory`. If it doesn't exist (in the first run), replace it with the database saved in the bundle (from the first step).

```
//check if present
NSFileManager*fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
success=[fm fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

if(success)
{
   NSLog(@"Already present");
}
else
{

   //Copy from bundle to DocumentsDirectory on first run. Where DB won't be available in DocumentsDirectory.
      NSString*bundlePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourDB" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSError*error;
success=[fm copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:databasePath error:&error];

 if(success)
 {
     NSLog(@"Created successfully");
 }

} // End of else when DB not present in documents directory.
```

After doing this you'll have the blank DB that you added in the bundle manually to documents directory, and all the changes will be performed on it (not on the bundle). After this you can proceed with the rest of `sqlite3` database manipulation functions.

**Edit:** Method to access DB

This is what i use to retrieve values from DB, just try this out.

```
if(sqlite3_open([dbpath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK) //Check if it opens properly
{
    NSString*queryStmt=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from sometable"];
    const char*querystmt=[queryStmt UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

  if(sqlite3_prepare(database, querystmt, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) // Check if prepare statment has no issues
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) // Consists of row.
        {
            NSString*thestring=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];// 0 will be first column
            NSLog(@"%@",thestring);
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement); //finalize statement
    }

    sqlite3_close(database); //Close database
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So far it worked half way. I can access the database and read one of the entries but it only has the first entry and not the other 3 rows I have in the database. Also when I do a  while loop (code for this is in link in question) I get an infinite loop repeating the contents of the first row. Any ideas on this issue?

Comment: @user1431272, hmmm if you mean the answer to question you linked, as far as i know it is called `prepare-step-finalize` but i don't see a finalize step. It may not be an issue, but still check on it. I'll edit the answer to include the accessing method. See if there is any change.

Comment: @user1431272, try the edited method. And let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: THANK YOU! It works great and after modifying your code a little bit I was able to get it to read the password and user names I inputed from the database. Thank you so much you saved me a lot of headache and tears!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be your database extension, create a DB called `Login.sqlite` rather than `Login.sql` as iPhone sqlite3 framework only recognizes `.sqlite` databases.

Then what you have coded will work.

Comment: I tried a .sqlite extension yesterday and it didn't change anything.